# Where did I find these numbers?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

I generated this number sequence by following a pattern. Can you determine that pattern?

> 1
>   120
>   10800
>   345600
>   3024000
>   15780000
>   220752000

Some rounding was used to get these numbers, so you may be slightly off when you calculate them yourself. If you find the pattern, you've found the answer.

Clue 1:

> Each number is X*Y, and both X and Y increase following their own pattern.

Clue 2:

> It's only a matter of time before someone finds the answer.

Comment: clue 2 is relevant? seems obvious

Comment: Clue 2 is relevant, but all in due time.

Comment: ohhh I get it ... lets see if I'm in **time** to solve it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These numbers are

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

times

> number of seconds in a second, minute, hour, day, week, month, year

where

> a month is taken to be about 30.4 days and a year 365 days, and the figure for a month rounded a bit (it isn't e.g. exactly 1/12 of the figure for a year).

Comment: about to post it! too fast , nice +1

Comment: darn! I was in the middle of typing up my answer and I saw you beat me to it! Well played